# How can I pass a time series consisting of both Mean and SE to the predict function in R

Tags: r, time-series, lm, predict

I have a time series but each value in the time series is a mean and SE. I do not have access to the raw data that calculated these Means and standard errors. I might get the sample size for each year, but I do not have that at the moment as well.

freqdata

| Year | Mean | SE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | 1 | 0.007777888 |
| 2015 | 0.9874615 | 0.007714999 |
| 2016 | 0.9264937 | 0.007230377 |
| 2017 | 0.8692902 | 0.006776196 |
| 2018 | 0.8199615 | 0.006796176 |
| 2019 | 0.7295428 | 0.006586196 |
| 2020 | 0.6881442 | 0.006776196 |
| 2021 | 0.6490948 | 0.005776191 |
| 2022 | 0.6122613 | 0.006776196 |

I would like to use this to create an exponential model like the one below (Note, I have used only Means as I dont know how to use the SE here).

```
exp_model <- lm(log(Mean)~ Year, data = freqdata)
```

and use predict and plot the model like below

```
plot(freqdata$Year, freqdata$Mean)
lines(x_axis, predict(exp_model, data.frame(Year=x_axis)), col='green')
```

However, I am unsure how to use the SE values of my time series for this prediction.

My understanding is that whatever be the SE in the time series, the predicted values of the Mean remains the same.
But the SE of the model itself should have a dependency on the SE of the time series. This SE is very important for me and I would later introduce that in the plot as well.

Question: How should I pass the SE of the time series to lm or/and predict functions in R so that the final SE of the model will depend on the SE of the time series.

If these are not the right functions to use, are there alternative functions in R that can be used ?

I searched answers here and generally on the internet but it appears all answers have time series without SE as input. Hence, it appears I am the only one who have a time series of this kind (which is a bit difficult to believe)

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat the regression on confidence intervals derived by the standard deviations. Since you want to extrapolate into the future, we could `merge` the respective years to the data so we can easier `predict`. It might be better to use `loess` here to avoid having to guess the polynomial structure of the model.

```
## merge prediction years to data
freqdata <- merge(freqdata, data.frame(Year=c(freqdata$Year, 2023:2028)), all=TRUE)

## 95% ci function
ci <- \(x) x[1] + 1.959964*x[2]*c(lo=-1, up=1)

## apply ci row-wise in data and cbind
freqdata <- cbind(freqdata, t(apply(freqdata[-1], 1, ci)))

## loess-regression, `poly`
fo <- y ~ Year  ## base formula, to be updated in each iteration

r <- sapply(c('Mean', 'lo', 'up'), \(x) {
  fit <- loess(update(fo, paste(sprintf('log(%s)', x), '~ .')), freqdata,
               control=loess.control(surface="direct"))
  pred <- predict(fit, newdata=freqdata)
  exp(pred)
})
            
## plot
with(freqdata, plot(Year, Mean, pch=20, ylim=range(r[, 2:3])))
Map(\(x, y) lines(freqdata$Year, r[, x], lty=y, col=4), 1:3, c(1, 2, 2))
legend('bottomleft', lty=1:2, col=4, legend=c('pred', '95% CI'), cex=.8)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
freqdata <- structure(list(Year = 2014:2022, Mean = c(1, 0.9874615, 0.9264937, 
0.8692902, 0.8199615, 0.7295428, 0.6881442, 0.6490948, 0.6122613
), SE = c(0.007777888, 0.007714999, 0.007230377, 0.006776196, 
0.006796176, 0.006586196, 0.006776196, 0.005776191, 0.006776196
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that your suggestion is to do a curve fit for the CI independent of the mean. This makes sense to me. However, I would be predicting this curve for future years. Each of the prediction for CI has its own SE. I can get this SE if I do se.fit=TRUE in the predict function.  To make errors add up, should I be adding up the SE (root mean squared?) and recalculating a new CI for each predicted year? I am no statistician and assumed this will get done under the hood if I use the correct predict function in R. But I am certainly okay to do this if there is no other alternative.

Comment: @PraveenJ I see. I elaborated on my idea in my answer accordingly and now used `loess` regression and `predict`. However, I think this indeed is not trivial and particularly the extrapolated CI might be too optimistic. Adding up uncertainties for time series and extrapolation, thus, would make sense to me. I recommend to ask the folks on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) who might be better equipped with statistical knowledge, you can link to this answer. Keep me posted.

Comment: Thank you again - I have posted in that forum as suggested. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599484/how-can-i-use-a-time-series-consisting-of-both-mean-and-se-to-obtain-predictions